# Where to handle AngualrJS backend errors

Tags: angularjs, error-handling, promise, angular-promise

In reviewing out AngularJS application I'm struck that I don't really know how to handle errors from the database at the Controller level.

We have a three tier structure `controller` -> `service` -> `rest`

The Rest service handles the calls to the backend database and returns a promise to mid tier service, which in most case hands it to the controller

**myController.js**

```
myService.getdata().then(function (result) {
  $scope.data = result
})
```

**myService.js**

```
this,getdata = function () {
  return RestService.get('url/to/my/data')
}
```

The `RestService` happily returns errors from the Back End API (via hapi/Boom) and these can be caught by either `myService` or `myController`. What I'm struggling with is constructing the error handler in the service rather than the controller.

My best attempt in the Controller is as follows:

```
  .then(function (result) {
    $scope.data = result
    // do something with the data
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error('data could not be loaded')
  })
  .finally(function () {
    // tidy up here
  })
```

I'd rather move the error handling into the service but am unsure how the controller would wait for the data to be avaialble to process...

Comment: well, apart from a [custom interceptor](https://plnkr.co/edit/6Xxyi2LNQ7iUoHsOI7Yf?p=preview) in `$httpProvider`, you can try just passing both callbacks: `this.getdata = function (success, error) { return RestService.get('url/to/my/data').then(success, error)`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey $http.success and $http.error were removed in AngularJS 1.6 if that's what you're talking about

Comment: I was talking about passing your own functions as parameters. They would work as callbacks that can be executed in the Service

Answer (score 0):

The best I have come up with is to handle errors in the service and create additional promises to send back to the controller:

```
this.getdata = function () {
  //returns the $q.resolve or $q.reject promises with customized data
  return RestService.get('url/to/my/data').then(function(response) {
    // format the data differently from response, etc.
    var _data = customProcessing(response.data);

    // you can even decide, on your own if there is an error
    // if(someCondition) { return $q.reject("Custom error"); }

    return $q.resolve(_data);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // throw up a modal, etc.
    var _error = customProcessing(error);
    return $q.reject(_error);
  }).finally(function() {
    //to do
  });
}
```

This example allows your service layer to act as middleware. It gets the data and then, after performing it's own functions it returns control back to the controller:

```
myService.getdata().then(function (data) {
  $scope.data = data;
}).catch(function(error) {
  //optional catch clause. I use it to stop loading spinners
  //or to show error message below a form
});
```

Here is a working example: https://plnkr.co/edit/35zx59yHUJ1Zrf5LWp3W?p=preview

Comment: That's what I was intending to do as well. However, If I follow the pattern above then I get a TypeError `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` which suggests that the service is not returning a Promise. Error happens whether I am forcing an error on the backend or not.

Comment: You should create a plunker (JS sandbox, https://plnkr.co/edit/) with the simplest example so we can help you debug